# How can I play an m3u8 with an HTML5 video tag on Chrome?

Tags: html5-video, m3u8

It seems that just adding the remote file in the src property is not enough for Chrome.

```
<video width="720" height="400" >
    <source src="http://mysite/master.m3u8" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `type="application/x-mpegURL"` on the source, or

```
<video width="720" height="400" src="http://mysite/master.m3u8"></video>
```